# How can one mute an application using pipewire from CLI

Tags: linux, audio, pipewire

I would like to automute certain audio clients when I want, without human intervention (e.g. pulling up `pavucontrol`) when using Fedora/pulsewire.  This worked before using `pacmd`, but that doesn't work under pipewire; and the replacement command, `pw-cli`, doesn't support set-sink-input-mute or set-source-output-mute.

`pw-cli` doesn't seem to support muting that I could see.  `pw-mon` shows a relevant change when using `pavucontrol` (or `easyeffects`) to mute a stream, but that didn't help me figure out how to do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late but i recently needed it too. Instead of pacmd you can use `pactl set-sink-input-volume <sink-id> <volume>`

Comment: This answer led me to the correct solution for me:  `pactl set-source-output-mute "$(pactl list  source-outputs | perl -ne '/^Source Output #(\d+)/ && { $sourceid=$1 }; /^\s+node.name = \"APPNAME\"/ && print $sourceid;')" toggle`

Comment: But isn't that PulseAudio command, not PipeWire?

Comment: @jarno Is, but `pactl` will work just fine if you have `pipewire-pulse`.